# My rails server exits automatically and now gives the following error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Macs-MBP:myapp mac$ rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    80: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    79: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    78: from /Users/mac/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    77: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    76: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    75: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    74: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    73: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    72: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    71: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    70: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    69: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    68: from /Users/mac/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    67: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    66: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    65: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    64: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    63: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    62: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    61: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    60: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    59: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    58: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    57: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    56: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    55: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    54: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    53: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    52: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    51: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    50: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    49: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    48: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    47: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    46: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    45: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    44: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    43: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    42: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    41: from config.ru:in `new'
    40: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    39: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    38: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    37: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    36: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    35: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    34: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    33: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    32: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    31: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    30: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    29: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    27: from /Users/mac/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    26: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    25: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    24: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    23: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    21: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    20: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    19: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    18: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    17: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    15: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    14: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    13: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    12: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    11: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker.rb:27:in `bootstrap'
    10: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:31:in `bootstrap'
     9: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     8: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
     7: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
     6: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
     5: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
     4: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:84:in `fetch'
     3: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `data'
     2: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `load'
     1: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `read'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mac/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    79: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    78: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    77: from /Users/mac/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    76: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    75: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    74: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    73: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    72: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    71: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    70: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    69: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    68: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    67: from /Users/mac/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    66: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    65: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    64: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    63: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    62: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    61: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    60: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    59: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    58: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    57: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    56: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    55: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    54: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    53: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    52: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    51: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    50: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    49: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    48: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    47: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    46: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    45: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    44: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    43: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    42: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    41: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    40: from config.ru:in `new'
    39: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    38: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    37: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    36: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    35: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    34: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    33: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    32: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    31: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    30: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    29: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    28: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    27: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    26: from /Users/mac/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    25: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    24: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    23: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    20: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    19: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    18: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    16: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    15: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    14: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    13: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    12: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    11: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    10: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker.rb:27:in `bootstrap'
     9: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:31:in `bootstrap'
     8: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     7: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
     6: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
     5: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
     4: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
     3: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:84:in `fetch'
     2: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `data'
     1: from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:91:in `load'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/mac/myapp/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mac/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions from the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line gives you the error:

```
Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/mac/myapp/config/webpacker.yml.
```

...and helpfully tells you what to do:

```
Please run rails webpacker:install
```